# Material UI: How to change DatePicker text and calendar icon color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I am trying to change the MUI X DatePicker (with Material UI) date text and calendar icon color.
I tried to change it passing style to InputProps, but it worked only for removing border.
Rather than that, nothing changes, I tried to apply style to theme.tsx, but it also didn't help.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DesktopDatePicker from "@mui/lab/DesktopDatePicker";
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    noBorder: {
      outline: "none",
      border: "none",
      color: "#fff",
    },
  })
);

export default function DatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (newvalue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newvalue);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
          inputFormat="dd/MM/yyy"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          InputProps={{
            classes: { notchedOutline: classes.noBorder },
          }}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**1st solution - using `sx` property**

You can set `sx` property to `<TextField/>` component in order to overwrite default style properties:

```
const color = "#c44242";
...
return (
       <DatePicker
          renderInput={(params) => {
            return (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                sx={{
                  svg: { color },
                  input: { color },
                  label: { color }
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
          ...other props
        />
  )
```

[Setting colors with sx prop](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-color-date-input-mui-using-sx-prop-mgemv?file=/demo.tsx)

**2nd solution - providing a custom theme**

You can also create a custom theme and overwrite colors inside it:

```
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiIconButton: {
        styleOverrides: {
          sizeMedium: {
            color
          }
        }
      },
      MuiOutlinedInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            color
          }
        }
      },
      MuiInputLabel: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            color
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Then you wrap your component with `ThemeProvdier`.

[Overriding Theme Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-color-date-input-mui-override-theme-qp4py?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Woah, I didn't know you can use the rule names in `sx`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me is as follows -
I used the `sx` property in `<TextField/>` which is also mentioned by [dmitriif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14190690/dmitriif).
The implementation looked something like this -

```
 <DateTimePicker
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            sx={{
              svg: { color: '#fff' },
              input: { color: '#fff' },
            }}
         />
     )}
  />
```

Answer (score -6):

Try to inspect element then you can see the styling of the inspected element. Inspect element is so useful.

[image]

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't answer the question directly.